# uninitialized constant IssueTrackers

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, errbit

I just upgraded Errbit after 2 years, when I click on the Apps I get the following error:

NameError: uninitialized constant IssueTrackers

This is the possible error location:

```
[PROJECT_ROOT]/models[PROJECT_ROOT].rb:123→ issue_tracker_configured?
[PROJECT_ROOT]/helpers[PROJECT_ROOT]s_helper.rb:47→ block in detect_any_apps_with_attributes
[PROJECT_ROOT]/helpers[PROJECT_ROOT]s_helper.rb:44→ each
[PROJECT_ROOT]/helpers[PROJECT_ROOT]s_helper.rb:44→ detect_any_apps_with_attributes
[PROJECT_ROOT]/helpers[PROJECT_ROOT]s_helper.rb:15→ any_github_repos?
[PROJECT_ROOT]/views[PROJECT_ROOT]s/index.html.haml:9→ app_views_apps_index_html_haml__FRAGMENT_
```

Full Trace:

http://pastebin.com/wfHFVsAp

Answer (score 0):

I just had to run my migrations:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```